# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' error even after grant the privileges to root @localhost in python pyspark

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark

I want to read the data from Mysql on terminal using JDBC driver in python pyspark. However, I keep getting the same issue of error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` error even after I've grant the privileges for the `root@localhost`.

My code:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users").option("dbtable","customers").option("user", "root").option("password","123@456").option("numPartitions",50).option("partitionColumn","ID").option("lowerBound", "1").option("upperBound", "100000").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").load().cache
```

I've grant privileges as suggested by many posted answers like:

```
    mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

change the host in the url

```
"url","jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:3306/users"
```